# Continued fraction expansion of PI not accurate?

Tags: c, double

I'm trying to write a Windows C program (Visual C++ 2019) to generate the [continued fraction expansion of π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Continued_fraction_expansion_of_%CF%80_and_its_convergents).

The correct values from [WolframAlhpa](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=pi) and [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001203) shows:

```
[3; 7, 15, 1, 292, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 14, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1,
```

However, my values start deviating after 14

```
[3; 7, 15, 1, 292, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 14, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 19,
```

Here's a [demo](https://onlinegdb.com/yCnOrGCbw) of the code running.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    long double u = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923;

    printf("[%lld; ",(unsigned long long)u);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        u = 1.0 / (u - floorl(u));
        printf("%lld, ",(unsigned long long)u);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Question**

Is the code losing some kind of decimal precision, causing the incorrect values?

Comment: It is bound to deviate at some point. The closest double representation of pi is 3.14159265358979311599796346854.

Comment: ...which works out to 884279719003555 × 2^-48 ≈ π - 1.22 × 10^-16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `long double` constants.  Append an `L`.  Otherwise you code is assigning a `double` value to `u` and not a `long double` one.

```
// long double u = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923;
long double u = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923L;
```

With `L`, my output was nearly the expected:

```
[3; 7, 15, 1, 292, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 14, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1,         My output
[3; 7, 15, 1, 292, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 14, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 84, ... WolframAlhpa
```

WolframAlhpa is using precision beyond my `long double`.

---

On some implementations (I'm thinking Visual C), `double` and `long double` are the same precision in which case appending an `L` will not change things.

---

Add `printf("%La\n", u);` after the `u` declaration to see what value code is truly using.

```
long double u = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923L;
printf("%La\n", u);

0x1.921fb54442d1846ap+1  // Your output may differ.
```

It is the continued fraction of that value (e.g. machine pi) code is calculating and not of [π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi).

---

Aside:

Best to use matching specifiers

```
//printf("[%lld; ",(unsigned long long)u);
  printf("[%llu; ",(unsigned long long)u);
```

Comment: @vengy I suspect VC may not provide a better numeric result as IIRC, `double` and `long double` have the same precision there - something allowed by C.  What is the result of `printf("%La\n", u);` for you?

Comment: It looks like @chux-ReinstateMonica's compiler is using the x87 extended-precision format, giving an exact value of 3.14159265358979323851280895940618620443274267017841339111328125 ≈ π + 5.02 × 10^-20.

Comment: I've updated the question to indicate it's a Windows C program (Visual C++ 2019). Even with the "L" suffix, it's still returning values 14, 3, 3, 23, ... Ran %La and it returned 0x1.921fb54442d18p+1 - The online gdb demo returns 0xc.90fdaa22168c235p-2 ... and better values 14, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, Thanks.

Comment: @vengy Note: On-line is apparently using 64-bit precision `long double`, like my machine.  The outputs have the same value, yet differ in format due to allowed differences in using `%La"`.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `u = 1.0 / (u - floorl(u));`, the first time the loop runs it's going to be

`u = 1.0/0.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923` and it will have more digits than current pi. So, for each iteration the number of digits of `u` keeps increasing and at some point, it exceeds the highest precision possible and the value is going to be rounded off.

Comment: I guess you meant `0.1415...` rather than `1415...` in the denominator. But in any case, this is inaccurate, since the actual denominator (assuming that `long double` is IEEE 754 binary64 format, which is what it appears to be on the OP's machine) will be `0.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875`.

Comment: What does "current pi" mean in your answer? (i.e., why "current"? π is a constant.) And how are you counting digits of the "current pi"? (Or of "u", for that matter?) What do you think the "highest precision possible" is?